# $f(0)>0$, and $f'(x)\le c \lt 1$ for all $x>0$. Prove that $f(x)= x$ has a solution.

Tags: real-analysis

$f:[0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ is continuous on its domain and differentiable on $(0, \infty)$, $f(0)>0$, and $f'(x)\le c \lt 1$ for all $x>0$.

Prove that the equation $f(x)= x$ has a solution in $[0, \infty)$.

I don't quite get what $f'(x)\le c \lt 1$ can help me here.

Answer (score 1):

By the mean value theorem $f(x) - f(0) = x f'(a_x)$ for some $a_x$ between $0$ and $x$. Therefore 
$$f(x) - f(0) \leq cx$$
This can be rewritten as
$$f(x) - x \leq f(0) + (c-1) x$$
The condition $c < 1$ implies $c - 1 < 0$. So for large enough $x$, $f(0) + (c-1)x < 0$. Hence
$f(x) - x$ is negative for large enough $x$. Now the intermediate value theorem is your friend...

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*

Consider the function $g(x) = f(x) - x$. We have $g(0) > 0$. Show that there exists a $z > 0$ such that $g(z) < 0$. Then use the Intermediate Value Property.

Answer (score 0):

A better way might be to consider $g(x)=f(x)-x$ and argue by contradiction. If $g(x)>0$ for all $x$, then $g'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$. However, the condition tells you that $g'(x) \leq c-1<0$ for all $x$.

Comment: But you need more than $g'(x)<0$, but rather some $\epsilon<0$ so that for all x $g'(x)<\epsilon$....

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: yes. That's what the condition gives us. I wasn't precise enough. Should I delete this answer?

Comment: One more question, in the question, what is difference between the condition $f'(x) \le c \lt 1$ and only $f'(x) \lt 1$

Comment: @user149131: That's what Thomas referred to in the first comment. I was a bit sloppy in writing it- do you want an edit? Or should I delete the answer-if it didn't help you?

Comment: Can you edit a little bit? Since I think the idea is pretty helpful.

Comment: @user149131: I think the idea of proof by contradiction might be more useful- so I changed the answer to this.

Comment: @voldemort But now we can only say there exist some $x$ so that $g(x) \le 0$. Is it enough to say there must be some $x$ so that $g(x)$ is negative?

Comment: I think this suffices to say that $g(x)$ must be $0$ for some $x$.